# How can I erase a key value pair in c++ map?

Tags: c++, maps

I'm working on a project that needs unique keys and values so I decided to use maps. Everything works expect for the case where someone may want to change the key value. I'm not sure why, but it causes a fragmentation fault. Can I not do this?

```
void Journal::set_id(int id){               // journal class
    if(join.count(id)){                     // join is: static map <int,string> join
        cout<<"Journal ID is already being used. Try again."<<endl;
    }
    else {
        join.erase (join.find(id));
        join.insert(pair<int,string>(id,name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant to say "where someone may want to change the key".

Comment: What are `Journal` and `join`? We need all the facts to answer properly! Also: make edits using the "edit" button, not in the comments ;)

Comment: Is that helpful in the code?

Comment: Given the context, I think people can figure it out. Generally it's a good idea to let people know, though - you'll get better, faster responses when people know what all the objects are.

Comment: What key value pair are you trying to erase?

Comment: So I didn't realize this until I read the other answers below, but I guess I'm trying to erase the same one I want to use to replace the other key. So What to do:

Comment: 1. erase key value pair matching id and 2. set a new key value pair using the new id (that I never passed in) [hand to face].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is flawed.

```
void Journal::set_id(int id){
    if(join.count(id)){
        cout<<"Journal ID is already being used. Try again."<<endl;
    }
    else {
        // When you hit this block of the code, there is nothing
        // in the map corresponding to 'id'.
        // join.find(id) returns the same iterator as join.end()
        // Calling erase() with that iterator is causing you the
        // problem.

        // Don't call erase. Just insert the new item.
        // join.erase (join.find(id));
        join.insert(pair<int,string>(id,name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @MikeH, most of us have done this sometime or other.

Answer (score 1):

You have just checked to make sure that `id` is not being used as a key in the map. If it is, you issue an error. So now you *know* that `id` is not in the map. If `id` is not in the map, `join.find(id)` will return `join.end()`, so you really didn't need to call `find` at all. But more importantly, you then call `join.erase(join.end())`, which is an error.

See [documention for std::map::erase() in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.

Comment: Thanks.I guess I've been looking at this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check whether the key is present, and insert it only if not found, you can simplify the code by just inserting the item, and then checking the return value to see if the insertion succeeded (which it won't if that key was already present).

```
void Journal::set_id(int id){
    if (!(join.insert(std::make_pair(id, name)).second))
        cout<<"Journal ID is already being used. Try again."<<endl;
}
```

This should also improve speed, since it only searches the tree once whereas code doing a `count` then an `insert` has to search it twice.